# matlab regular expression: word starts and ends with space '\<\s.*\s\>'

Tags: regex, matlab

In matlab, to find words starting and ending both with space by using '\<\s.*\s\>'

commands:

```
str = 'A body or collection of such stories s@@5%%suchstro end';

regexp(str, '\<\s.*\s\>', 'match')
```

result returns nothing.

However, same commands in Octave, returns: '  body or collection of such stories s@@5%%suchstro '

`'\<\s.*?\s\>'` also works in Octave, but not in matlab.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What would you expect as output?

Comment: I would expect to see  ' body or collection of such stories s@@5%%suchstro ' for '\<\s.*\s\>', I just don't understand why matlab returns nothing.

Comment: Loose the `\<` `\>`.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by that? isn't it that \< and \> are used to indicate the starting and the ending of words?

Answer (score 0):

`\<\s.*?\s\>` reads as: beginning of word, whitespace, anything, whitespace, end of word. But a word cannot begin with whitespace, so this pattern does not match anything.

The pattern `\s\<.*?\>\s` returns

```
` body or collection of such stories s@@5%%suchstro `
```

which is probably not what you wanted. This is not a collection of words, but everything together, because the match is greedy. Make it lazy:

```
regexp(str, '\s\<?.*?\>\s', 'match')

' body '    ' collection '    ' such '    ' s@@5%%suchstro '
```

Also, you don't want to capture those spaces, do you? Use lookahead and lookbehind for them:

```
regexp(str, '(?<=\s)\<?.*?\>(?=\s)', 'match')

'body'    'or'    'collection'    'of'    'such'    'stories'    's@@5%%suchstro'
```

Finally... s@@5%%suchstro is probably not a word, is it? Maybe you need `\w`, word characters, in place of `\.`

```
regexp(str, '(?<=\s)\<?\w*?\>(?=\s)', 'match')

'body'    'or'    'collection'    'of'    'such'    'stories'
```

In this form, the lazy/greedy distinction is no longer an issue, so the expression can be simplified to `(?<=\s)\<\w*\>(?=\s)` or even to `(?<=\s)\w*(?=\s)` since spaces provide word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learn a lot for your reply. BTW, do you know why '\<\s.*?\s\>' in matlab matches nothing? (i.e. ans = {} )

Comment: This is explained in the first two lines of my answer. Already `\<\s` cannot match anything, because it's asking for a "word that begins with whitespace", which is a contradiction.