# Octave - Finding words in a string using regex

Tags: regex, matlab, octave

In Octave, I am finding words ending with only whitespaces, or either a comma or a period followed by whitespace(s).

The following is my code:

```
str = 'Hello, I am kjd#(@*#@m, aa.aa.aa.aa. It was nice meeting you.';
regexp(str, "\[a-zA-Z]+\[,.]?\s+", 'match')
```

This should return the words
`Hello`, `I`, `am`, `It`, `was`, `nice`, `meeting`, `you`.
However, it only returns `was`. I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I've also tried tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29174222/6213337, but it returns `ans = {}(1x0)`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to escape `[` and `]`

Comment: @rock321987, Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean? Should I remove `[` and `]`?

Comment: Try this `[a-zA-Z]+[,.]?\\s+`

Comment: @rock321987 Returns `Hello,`, `I`, `am`, `m,`, `aa.`, `It`, `was`, `nice`, `meeting`. Not what I need but it's an improvement though, thank you.

Comment: update me if it is working or not

Comment: @rock321987 I don't know much about word boundary too. But I've tried what you said and both return `ans = {}(1x0)`. I've also tried mixing your first answer with the answer on my link. No luck.

Comment: I will update it..Its not word boundary

Comment: I have written the solution..Check it

Comment: I'd use [`(?<!\\S)\\p{L}++(?!\\p{P}\\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/dV7zL8/1). The regex flavor in Matlab is PCRE, not Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
str = 'Hello, I am kjd#(@*#@m, aa.aa.aa.aa. It was nice meeting you.';
regexp(str, "(?:^|\\s+)([a-zA-Z]+)(?=[,.]?(?:$|\\s))", 'matches')
```

Answer (score 2):

Matlab uses PCRE regex flavor, thus, the regex pattern you need can be short and compact and quite comprehensive:

```
str = 'Hello, I am kjd#(@*#@m, aa.aa.aa.aa. It was nice meeting you.';
regexp(str, "(?<!\\S)\\p{L}++(?!\\p{P}\\S)", 'match')
print match
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dV7zL8/1) and [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/mEKiDM) demos.

The regex matches:

- `(?<!\S)` - check if there is no non-whitespace character before the current location in string, and if there is not, go on matching....
- `\p{L}++` - any 1+ letters (possessively, not allowing backtracking, thus, the next check will only be performed once after the last letter matched) that are NOT followed with...
- `(?!\p{P}\S)` - any punctuation and then a non-whitespace (`(?!...)` is a *negative lookahead* that fails a match if its subpattern matches to the right of the current location in the string).